# iOS Universal links : Tapping universal link inside the Application redirects me to safari instead of continuing in the application

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios-universal-links

I am using `third party SDK` which internally calls `UIApplication.shared.OpenUrl` to open a universal link within the application.

But instead of getting call-back in `application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity` the link is opened in Safari.

I want to continue handling the Universal link within the application, rather than move to Safari.

> Note: I cannot use Custom URL scheme due to project restrictions.
> When I use iPhone **Notes application** that universal link; tapping on the link opens my application.

https://frozen-garden-86689.herokuapp.com/apple-app-site-association

Comment: Can you show the universal link format?

Comment: @son I have added the url my question.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add associated domains in your app and upload a file on your website on this path

```
https://yourwebsite.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association
```

in apple-app-site-association you have to add exact this JSON

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [{
            "appID": "xxxxxx", // your appID here like 2u19IxOp1.com.mybudleid.app
            "paths": ["/g/*"] //it should be same
        }]
    }
}
```

after putting exact JSON on the path, hit the path on the browser it should show this JSON file

important!* and must add the associated domain in your Xcode project which will be `applinks:yourwebsite.com`

and here your links will start redirecting to your app instead of safari

Comment: I have already done that. I am able to redirect to app when the link is clicked from Notes application/.

The problem is when I am in the application and Universal link is clicked within the application, I  am redirected to Safari, where I see option to open the same in app.

I do not want  to move away from the application, if the link is clicked with the application.
I am using SDK which internally calls UIApplication.shared.OpenUrl and I am redirected to Safari

Comment: "paths": ["/Profile/help",
                  "/Home/*",
                  "/Messages"] don't use this path, the app not open because your app architecture is not enough mature, and it doesn't find a way redirect on path, use "paths": ["/g/*"]  and manage in-app how to redirect using links like mywebsite.com/groups?inviteid=x3e4 so you have to get the groups from url through substring method and then you will redirect to there

Comment: Tried, doesn't help. I am still being redirected from my application to Safari

Comment: @Manoj did you manage to solve this? running into the same problem..

Comment: @barYes, I did solve this. I will upload the solution here as soon as I can. If you are stuck, please connect me via mail for faster resolution. Check my about section

Comment: hello @Manoj can you update the question with your solution?

Comment: looking for a solution to this as well